# Uso de CLASS na semântica do HTML5

Tags: html5

Estou atualizando a estrutura do meu site para a semântica do HTML5, e isso me gerou algumas dúvidas. Tais como:

Preciso ajustar minha imagem no site, posso colocar o  `class` no figure?
O que posso fazer para ficar dentro do padrão HTML5?

```
<figure class="ajusteimg">
        <img src="./propaganda_rotativa/supportgv.png" />
</figure>
```

Answer (score 4):

O facto de usares `figure` já é usar HTML semântico e a razão dessas tags terem sido criadas.

Se precisas de classes para efeitos de CSS ou para o JavaScript é útil usares classes.

Podes sempre tentar diminuir o uso de classes e fazer o JavaScript e CSS mais dependentes do HTML, mas usar não tem mal nenhum, nem é contraproducente à ideia de HTML semântico.

Answer (score 2):

Sim, você pode! Porque `class` é um atributo global.

Como a própria documentação diz: 'This element only includes the global attributes.'

Referências:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/figure
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes

Answer (score 1):

Sim pode usar class no figure

```css
figure {
  float: right;
  width: 30%;
  text-align: center;
  font-style: italic;
  font-size: smaller;
  text-indent: 0;
  border: thin silver solid;
  margin: 0.5em;
  padding: 0.5em;
}
```

```html
    <figure>
    <p><img src="https://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/eiffel.jpg"
    width="136" height="200"
    alt="Torre Eiffel">
    <figcaption>Miniatura da 
    torre Eiffel no 
    Parque Mini-France</figcaption>
    </figure>
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```css
figure {
  float: right;
  width: 30%;
  text-align: center;
  font-style: italic;
  font-size: smaller;
  text-indent: 0;
  border: thin silver solid;
  margin: 0.5em;
  padding: 0.5em;
}
```

```html
    <figure>
    <img src="https://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/eiffel.jpg"
    width="136" height="200"
    alt="Torre Eiffel">
    <figcaption>Miniatura da 
    torre Eiffel no 
    Parque Mini-France</figcaption>
    </figure>
```

OBS: O Elemento figcaption utilizado para marcar uma legenda para conteúdos inseridos com uso do elemento   `<figure>`. Sempre deve vir entre o elemento   `<figure>`, ou seja, deve constar como elemento-filho do elemento   `<figure>`. A tag  `<figcaption>`  só é válido dentre do   `<figure>`.

> já que no comentário foi abordado a necessidade da tag p ...

Vale salientar que o elemento   `<figure>` e   `<figcaption>` não serve somente para imagens e fotos, mas também serve para diagramas, gráficos, textos (como poemas, código-fonte, citações etc), um trecho de código - com tags html - ex: `<p>`.

[Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/figure)

[HTML Global Attributes](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_standardattributes.asp)

[Saiba mais](http://www.maujor.com/blog/2010/04/13/os-elementos-figure-e-figcaption-da-html5/)

Comment: Qual a necessidade de usar <p> dentro do figure?

Comment: veja os dois executes , um com tag p e o segundo sem tag p